# My Array isn't holding anything?

Tags: c++, arrays

For some reason I cannot store data in an array if it is a pointer. If I stop it from being a pointer it works perfectly, but I need to have an array that holds a variable amount so it must be a pointer. Here is my code. Why is this array not storing more than one vertex at a time?

```
MVertex* Vertices = new MVertex[VertexCount];
//MVertex Vertices[4];
string LDum;
getline(Input, LDum);
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    MVertex V;
    string Line;
    getline(Input, Line);
    istringstream ISS(Line);
    string X, Y, Z;
    ISS >> X >> Y >> Z;
    V.X = atoi(X.c_str());
    V.Y = atoi(Y.c_str());
    V.Z = atoi(Z.c_str());
    Vertices[i] = V;
}
Input.close();
GraphicsDevice->CreateVertexBuffer(4 * sizeof(MVertex), 0, MFVF,
    D3DPOOL_MANAGED, &MVertexBuffer, NULL);
VOID* pVoid;
MVertexBuffer->Lock(0, 0, (void**)&pVoid, 0);
memcpy(pVoid, Vertices, sizeof(Vertices));
MVertexBuffer->Unlock();
int Size = sizeof(Vertices);
delete[] Vertices;
```

Comment: What is the value of `VertexCount`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that everything else has been set up correctly, this is most likely to be your problem:

```
memcpy(pVoid, Vertices, sizeof(Vertices))
```

That works on arrays because `sizeof(Vertices)` returns the size of your array.  But if `Vertices` is a pointer, it will return the size of a pointer.  You need to do `4 * sizeof(MVertex)`.

Comment: Yes i filled that in and it all works. Very Happy.. thank you!

Comment: Please consider Bartek's answer as more appropriate.  You can access the vector as a pointer if you use `&Vertices[0]`

Comment: Or `Vertices.data()` in C++11. (that was even in MSVS2010).

Answer (score 2):

> but I need to have an array that holds a variable amount so it must be
> a pointer

### No.

No, it doesn't have to be a pointer. Simply use `std::vector<MVertex>` instead.

And your code doesn't work because of `sizeof(Vertices)`, which will indeed give you whole array size for array types, but only the pointer size for pointer types.

That's another reason why pointer types used as arrays are particularly bad: there's essentially no way to get the size of the array; hacks similar to `strlen` are extremely terrible non-solutions and C relicts.

### Important things to note here

1. Pointers **are not** arrays.
2. **Do not** use pointers in C++ if you don't have to and you don't know what you are doing.